# Find the commutator subgroup of a certain group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am given the group $H$ of matrices

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
0&1\\
\end{bmatrix},$$

where $a \neq 0$ and $a,b  \in\mathbb{R}$. How do I find the commutator subgroup of this group?

I found by the definition of a commutator of elements from $H$ that $H' \subseteq Sl_2(\mathbb{R}) $, but I do not know how to take it from there.

Comment: why not start off by seeing what values of $a$ and $b$ make the commutator $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}=1$ for arbitrary elements $g$ and $h$ of $H$.

Answer (score 4):

Take a typical commutator $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$, where

$$g = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$h = \begin{pmatrix} a' & b' \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

and calculate $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$.  At least get your hands dirty before asking the question.

Comment: I did that already and got that the commutator is a matrix that has 1 on the diagonal, at the position (1,2) it has some real number and at the position (2,1) it has 0. Which makes it contained in a group that contains matrices of that form (and those are matrices for which the determinant is 1). I do not know how to show that the commutator subgroup is exactly equal to this group I found.

Comment: I got $$ghg^{-1}h^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & (ab'-a'b+b-b') \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$Can you show that $$ab'-a'b+b-b'$$ can be any real number you want?  Why not set $a=a'$ so that this becomes $$a(b'-b) - (b'-b).$$ Now, $b'-b$ can be anything you want, and so can $a \neq 0$.

Comment: Oh right, I get it now. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome $\space$